# Does system C support tri-state logic?

Tags: systemc, tri-state-logic

Does System C support tri-state logic?  That is, bits that can get `0`, `1` or `X`, where `X` means "*unknown*"?

If it does, does it also support vectors that can contain `X`es, including logic and arithmetic operations?

Comment: Tri-state actually has `Z` value, rather than `X`. It means hi-impedance, and in practice means that the output is electrically disconnected from the input. OTOH, `X` is an unknown, or don't-care logical state, which can be either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

- http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/data_types2.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC#Data_types

It does not have tri-state variables, but quad-state (is that correct? :P) variables (0,1,X,Z). More about it in the above links. It also supports vectors of those variables.

Hope I helped you a little bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you're looking for the sc_logic and sc_lv types which are 4 state variables: 0, 1, X, and Z.  Pay attention to how they interact when you resolve them together.  There's a nice tables on the asic-world.com site taken directly from the SystemC User Manual.

Note though that this doesn't work like in Verilog where X can also act as a wildcard.  I had to build my own function to add that functionality.